# How to access\require a js file from another folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory structure,

```
 --- root
  |--- server
     |--- lib
        |--- core
           |--- Test.js
           |--- Test2.js
  |---config 
          |--- Common.js
```

in my test.js I require common.js files so I use this

var test = require("...../config/common.js"), it shows "can't find the module Cannot find module ' ...../config/common.js"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be:

```
var test = require("../../../config/common.js")
```

Answer (score 1):

**with normal rquire using express**

var test = require("../../../config/common.js")

**or with es6 you can do it like this way**

import test from ("../../../config/common.js")